# PHP scheduling a task on webhosting without SSH/Console

Tags: php, server, pthreads, schedule

I have a php website that has a script that executes an update for my database with data from an external API. The script itself works perfectly fine but i need to time it so that it executes it every monday at 2:30 AM. I am using a webhosting where SSH is not available neither is any form of command execution such as `exec()` or `passthru()`. I've also looked at CRON jobs but i can't use that either because i have no access to a console.

An other option i found was using threads with phthreads. But it seemed that i need an extra libary (PECL) to use it, but again because i can't use any console i can't install that dependency.

So another solution i came up with myself is the idea of stealing a request of the first user that visits the website. I know it's not a beautiful solution that's why i want to ask if there are some other options for me where i can schedule a task. Or is stealing the request the only option here? Or did i make a mistake in my assumptions?

Also a VPS is no option for me.

Sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language.

Comment: The first question to ask here is: what is your hosting panel? Is it cpanel? What version is? Then, we can talk. :)

Comment: I have no hosting panel or cpanel, i can only access my web root via ftp and database via sql connection

Comment: Complex then. You are pretty much screwed.

The only thing that comes to my mind is a SQL trigger that does an HTTP request. Not all the vendors support HTTP Requests though, so you have to check. Good luck!

Comment: Do you have a time stamp field in the database table?

Comment: Yes i have a created_date in my database rows. The database is a mySql database. Can i schedule HTTP requests with sql? I already have an route (/update) that will start the update. Ofc i will add authentication later

Comment: Hmm maybe i can use something like this: https://atrigger.com/

Comment: I was going to suggest a simple function that tests if the database needs to be updated. Atrigger looks like it would certainly do the trick; but at the cost of the possibility of a malicious user triggering the update at any time.

Comment: Hmm ye i think your solutions is better but i don't know how i can implement it since mysql doesn't have a HTTP request function (atleast to my knowledge) unlike msSQL. Or do you know some other way to trigger my webserver somehow?

Comment: By the way thanks for all the comments you've helped me great so far

Comment: Any time a request for a web page comes in, your web server goes into action.  So with atrigger, you'd have your updating script somewhere that it could be accessed via an URL.  I don't particularly like that option, though.  The less you have exposed to the world the better.  However, that option does give you the ability to schedule it at a specific time.  My option would require that the first user to view your web page would trigger the update script.  This could potentially give one user a bad experience, but it might be what has to be done.  I'll put an example up with some code...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to let your visitors trigger the update.

- The advantage to this is you are not exposing your updating script to the world.
- The disadvantage is that your database will not be updated until the visit of your first user after 2:30 am on Mondays, and that first user will have to wait for the database to be updated.

Add this to your script:

```
/**
 * Checks if the database's last update was before 
 * Monday at 02:30
 *
 * @param \DateTime Time of last update.  Must be converted to DateTime object
 * @return boolean
 */
function databaseIsOutOfDate(DateTime $createDate) {

  // find the last Monday at 2:30 am.
  $monday = (new DateTime())->modify('tomorrow')->modify('previous monday')->format('Y-m-d 02:30:00');
  $lastUpdated = $createDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  return ($lastUpdated < $monday);
}

$date_time_from_database = '2019-05-27 02:30:00'; // this date value comes from your database
$last_updated = new DateTime($date_time_from_database);  

if(databaseIsOutOfDate($last_updated)) {
  print "Updating database, please try again later";
  // trigger your update script
  die; // if you continue, you'll have race condition.
}

print "continue with script";
```

Comment: Aah sorry that won't do because the update takes more than 50 minutes. During that time the website isn't reachable.

Comment: Is there a possible way to keep a request alive? With something like sleep()

Comment: ah, bummer.  However... now that I stop to think about it, you could incorporate this and have atrigger call this page.  But... then you have a 50 minute period where any hits would start the process all over :(  During that 50 minutes, what do you do to ensure that you're serving good data?  I think the solution might lie more in reducing the time for updating:  Are you destroying all your data, or are you appending rows?  Is it necessary to only update once a week, or can it be updated daily (with fewer records)

Comment: re: sleep-- no, that's not what you're looking for.  sleep just stops execution of a script for a period of time.  To prevent a script from timing out, you have to change the max execution time https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: wait... how do you know it takes 50 minutes?